# Writing the flutter code on a server and implementing it inside my application

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

Is it possible to write a flutter code and save it inside Database and then send it to a flutter application and implement this code .. Is this possible?

We see that it is possible to write flutter code on the web and make a run for it, for example: https://flutlab.io/editor

What I want to do is write the code and save it as a string inside Database. Then send it through the api to my filter application and the application takes this to the string and executes it as a flutter code written inside the application

Comment: What you're talking about it's called "code push" and it's not possible in Flutter because, once you compile the code, AOT is being used and JIT no longer work.

Comment: Can something like this be built from scratch?? Or is it not possible at all?

Comment: not possible at the moment and I don’t see it possible in the near future (and maybe never will be)

Comment: After a very long search, can you take a look at this? https://github.com/Norbert515/flutter_experiment_phone_ide   https://github.com/Norbert515/flutter_ide

Comment: Again, that's JIT running... you can't compile and get apps into the Store with JIT. Once you compile, it goes to AOT which doesn't allow code push. What you just send is the exact same as https://dartpad.dev

Comment: You'll have to create, like them, an entire IDE which it will be AOT compilation to have JIT running embedded code with horrible performance to serve not other prepuce other than coding like the one I sent you.

Comment: oh, and your "app" will be running on debug mode... which most apps and services will not run as expected. Not to mention that every time you open the app you will have to fetch the code, compile, wait for the engine to start, etc and will feel like coding on DartPad

Comment: Is it possible to look at this package?
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_code_push

Answer (score 3):

No (un)fortunately. Dart uses an AOT and JIT and you need to learn about those to understand the reasoning behind this. You can learn more about them here: https://dart.dev/faq#q-which-is-faster--aot--or-jit-compiled-code

Comment: Is it possible to look at this package?
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_code_push